# "his or her head in the clouds" meaning

Tags: meaning, idioms

> Horoscope: You'll make a risqué comment to a boss who lately has had his or her head in the clouds…

From the above sentence I can understand that a person is going to make an indecent comment to his/her boss. I couldn't get what the rest of the sentence meant. The above sentence is taken from an email I got.

Comment: http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/have+head+in+the+clouds

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To have your [head in the clouds](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/have+head+in+the+clouds) can mean to be unaware of what is going on because of daydreaming (thinking private thoughts preventing you from paying attention to what's important)

> Perhaps she was right, perhaps he was in love, then again, perhaps not. He walked the twenty or so yards to where he'd parked the Mini, and walked nonchalantly past it, with his hands in his pockets, his [head in the clouds](http://books.google.com/books?id=EvhnWE-vZzwC&pg=PA8&dq=%22head+in+the+clouds%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Po_wUpiICaaAygH1voGIDQ&ved=0CEEQ6AEwBTge#v=onepage&q=%22head%20in%20the%20clouds%22&f=false).

or to think impractically because you believe in your own ideas or fantasies and not enough of reality

> [President Johnson had concluded regarding Peruvian leader Bélaunde, after he had] rattled on about his grandiose plans for the “marginal highway” and South American physical integration, that Belaúnde “not only has his [head in the clouds](http://books.google.com/books?id=P3c_3-Ef2-gC&pg=PA111&dq=%22head+in+the+clouds%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Po_wUpiICaaAygH1voGIDQ&ved=0CEcQ6AEwBjge#v=onepage&q=%22head%20in%20the%20clouds%22&f=false), he's got his feet in the clouds, too.”

The [example](http://dailylivehoroscope.com/horoscope/pisces/1) you give is a horoscope reading that's floating around on the Internet. As such, it's a prediction, with about as much value as a fortune cookie prediction.

Edited to add an interpretation: You will say something off-color to shock a boss into paying attention to you when you are trying to work with him.

Comment: @mplungjan Not true, because Susan has interpreted *risqué* more correctly than you. To my boss, I'd never dare suggest: "get a hotel room". :-)

Comment: It was not until I commented on this answer, that an interpretation was even given. The real question was about heads in the clouds - a bit disappointing not even getting one upvote for linking to the same dictionary first. Anyway. I amended my answer. Off colour does not have to be risqué by the way: "jokes, prose, poems, black comedy, blue comedy, insult comedy, cringe comedy and skits that deal with topics that may be considered to be in poor taste or overly vulgar"

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand it either. "Head in the clouds" means the person is not paying much attention to what is happening around them, and has their attention on their own thoughts, or their head is filled with unrealistic ideas.

Perhaps the idea is to shock the person out of their reverie by giving them a kind of jab in the hypothalamus. In any case, without context, I don't see any obvious connection.

Answer (score 0):

[have one's head in the clouds](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/have+head+in+the+clouds)

> Fig. to be unaware of what is going on from fantasies or daydreams. "Bob, do you have your head in the clouds?" asked the teacher. She walks around all day with her head in the clouds. She must be in love.

[risqué](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/risqu%C3%A9)

> Suggestive of sexual impropriety; bordering on the indelicate.

The horoscope is predicting that you will get annoyed with your boss because he/she does not seem to pay much attention lately. So annoyed, you will suggest something inappropriate to try get him/her to snap out of it.

Comment: Yes, I got this from horoscope mail.